# How to send parameter in return_url query string in stripe paymentIntent while confirming paymentIntent

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments, stripe-payment-intent

I want to define custom parameter like "language=en" for return_url in confirm paymentIntent. For eg:

`return_url = "https://www.example.com/thankyou?language=en"`

When confirming paymentIntent, theres an option to set return_url. However, when I define parameter in return_url query string like above and when it redirects customer to return_url, it deletes the query string data. Is there a way I can send parameter in return_url query string?

I am aware of metadata. I am already using it, metadata will not solve my purpose. I want to have this parameter via query string only.

Thank  you!

I tried sending parameter in return_url query string and it did not work. For eg:

`return_url = "https://www.example.com/thankyou?language=en"`

Comment: (1) Try changing `thankyou?language=en` to `thankyou%3Flanguage%3Den` (2) if it still fails, you may create a new file `thankyouen.html` which will redirect to `thankyou?language=en` by javascript

Comment: How are you confirming the PI? Using Stripe.js? Which function? I'm unable to replicate this – query parameters in my `return_url` value with [`confirmPayment`](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_payment) persist on redirect.